# Windows Phone Authenticated Cloud storage application

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I'm looking at creating a cloud storage application for a project. I wish to use C#, and it will be using a location based authentication system. It will work as follows: The user wishes to login. They enter their credentials, and the web based portion will verify the location (and some other attributes of the device) of the user using the mobile device. If correct, the phone will send an acknowledgement to the web portion, which in turn will send a one time code to the device, which the user will then use to login to the cloud storage.
My question is as follows: What technologies will be necessary for this project? I will obviously need the relevant SDK for the windows phone part, but what will I need for the cloud storage portion in terms of languages, SDKs? Could I use Google, or Amazon Cloud?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would look at Azure Mobil services. It handles authentication for google, facebook, MSN, etc. It  would also be a viable solution if you want to move your application to other platforms.

You can sign up for a free thirty day trial to check it out.

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-windows-phone-get-started/